# Date and Time plot

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I'm using Excel VBA to import a text file and analyse data.

I'd like the x-axis with date and time format.

The original file includes the following string for time.

"20200324160900340", i.e "YYYYMMddhhmmss.milliseconds".

I have a function to delete milliseconds and transform this string into another one with format "2020/03/24 16:09:00".

Finally I can plot the data with Y-values using the following:

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set CH1 = sh.ChartObjects(1).Chart

[...]

With CH1

    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = Elapsed 'Double Values
        .XValues = Time 'String Values format "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        .Name = File_name
    End With

    .HasTitle = True

    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    End With

End With
```

The graph is plotted correctly but I cannot see the time values and if I force them manually I see something like "01-01-1900", which is nonsense.

Comment: "I have a function to delete milliseconds"... can you [edit] your question with that code? Your question should have a [reprex]

Comment: You cannot plot STRINGS on a chart. Convert the time strings into numbers (date/time values) and then you will be able to plot them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot STRINGS on a chart. Convert the time strings into numbers (date/time values) and then you will be able to plot them correctly.

Below is a VBA function that will convert your text strings into Excel date/time values...

```
Function TextToDateTime(s)
    Dim yy, mm, dd, hh, mn, ss

    yy = Mid(s, 1, 4)
    mm = Mid(s, 5, 2)
    dd = Mid(s, 7, 2)
    hh = Mid(s, 9, 2)
    mn = Mid(s, 11, 2)
    ss = Mid(s, 13, 2)

    TextToDateTime = DateSerial(yy, mm, dd) + TimeSerial(hh, mn, ss)

End Function
```

Note that these values will look similar to this:  `43914.6729166667`.

That is exactly what you want. Should you wish to see the date-time values in a more friendly way, use number formatting to produce something like, `2020-03-24 16:09:00`.